# LAMP: Set Document Root for Specific Directory

Tags: php, apache, lamp

So I must upload the CMS that I've been creating in the development environment to my company's server to show the client. But the software I created was built in the document root, and the company wants me to upload it to a folder on the server. Is there any way to set the document root dynamically with PHP, or to include an .htaccess or some such thing in a single folder on a server?

I suppose I could also juse create some global var with

```
$DOCUMENT_ROOT = dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
```

And reference that at the beginning of my paths, but I am looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Need more info here. The name of the directory you're trying to deploy this to, whether or not there are other .htaccess files defined in the document root, what kind of PHP application you are trying to deploy, whether url rewriting is in use... even if you don't know the answers to these, provide what you do know.

Comment: directory is http://www.mytestwebsite.com/test/
Yes there is a .htaccess in the root directory
I am deploying a CMS (based on wordpress-mu)
URL rewriting is in use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need to define a baseUrl that is available throughout your application. If the client is getting antzy to see your work, tell them to register a subdomain to throw it on.